# Using asp button to perform update on checked RadGrid Rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Telerik Grid. In that I have Check box  for each row. Now I want that when I check more than one row and click on Asp button then it should update the selected rows. Now when I used:

```
protected void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridDataItem dataItem in invMenusAccessRadGrid.MasterTableView.Items)
            {

            }
        }
```

I am not able to further implement inside the loop to get selected values.

Comment: protected void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridDataItem dataItem in invMenusAccessRadGrid.MasterTableView.Items)
            {
 
            }
        }

Comment: what is your question?  Are you asking us to write the code inside the foreach?

Comment: yes if you could or atleast guide how to proceed

Comment: Since "e" will return only single selected row on GridEvents

Comment: Isn't there a RadGrid.SelectedItems list?

Comment: protected void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            foreach (GridDataItem dataItem in invMenusAccessRadGrid.SelectedItems)
            {

            }
        }